# Sum and capital pi notation with explicit cases

Tags: summation, notation, pi

This may be more about math syntax than math. I am uncertain about **how to write pi and sum notations when you are not "looping" through a set of consecutive numbers, but rather through a set of implicit cases**. So rather than this:
$$\prod^n_{i=0}(something),\qquad i=0,1,2,3, ..., n$$

I would like $i$ to refer to a table for example (not sure of correct notation):

$$\prod_{i}(something),\qquad i=0,12,4,5 \;\;(explicitly\;stated\;values)$$

How could I express this in the pi notation? Is the above notation correct?

---

### An example:

In my example we have a molecule with a number of atoms $n_e$ of a certain element $e$, and a number $n_{i_e}$ of each isotope $i_e$ of that element:

$$n_e!\prod_{i_e}\frac{1}{n_{i_e}!}$$

And for all elements $e$:

$$\prod_{e}n_e!\prod_{i_e}\frac{1}{n_{i_e}!}$$

This formula is used for calculating the numbers of configurations a molecule with this composition has. So imagine a completely made up molecule C16O4 with these isotopes:

[image]

Only taking carbon into consideration the number would be:

$$n_e!\prod_{i_e}\frac{1}{n_{i_e}!}=(14+2)!\frac{1}{14!2!}$$

And if we take all elements into consideration:

$$\prod_{e}n_e!\prod_{i_e}\frac{1}{n_{i_e}!}=(14+2)!\frac{1}{14!2!}(3+1+0)!\frac{1}{3!1!0!}$$

I would like $\prod_e$ to say "For all elements" and $\prod_{i_e}$ to say "For all isotopes in element e". Is this syntax right?

Comment: You can write $S = \{1, 12, 102\}$, $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

I am no professor in mathematics but I have seen (in many different places) that one writes text under the summation symbol exactly as you wrote above. Something like
$$
\sum_{all \ x \ such \ that ...}=...
$$
as you can see this easily creates "ugly" expressions but if you keep your text short it is definitely viable. If you would like to use a certain sequence of numbers as indexes you can give the definition of  the sequence like
$$
\sum_{x=2k+3,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}}=...
$$
I hope this helped :)